# Command for "go to the sheet with the name that I wrote in cell C19" (VBA-Excel)

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code which "20y" is the sheet name that I want to change it at any time by simply adding the name of the sheet to one cell (e.g. lets say C19). I want the program to be more flexible and read the name of the sheet from cell C19, so I can simply change it to what I want (e.g. 20y or 10y or 5y,...).
Thanks a lot!

```
Range("A19:B19").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("B19").Select
Sheets("20y").Select
Range("A2:B2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Histogram").Select
Range("A19").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Best,
Neos

Comment: Use a [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro to alter a hyperlink in the cell when you change the value.

Comment: @Jeeped OP wants to select the sheet and copy stuff so that won't work unless I am misunderstanding OP's intent. Edit: lol realized your intent when I wrote my comment below XD

Comment: I would store cell C19 to a variable then do something like `worksheets([variable]).select` in place of `Sheets("20y").Select`. You would need to run the macro unless you do it via worksheet change as Jeeped suggests XD

Comment: @findwindow - now that I've reread the narrative I think you may be right. My suggestion solves the problem described in the title but the narrative is a different story.

Comment: @Jeeped I think we each got half of the answer ^_^;

Answer (score 2):

You could simply add:

```
target_sheet = Sheets(1).Range("c19").Value
```

and replace Sheets("20y").Select by

```
Sheets(target_sheet).Select
```

of course, replace Sheets(1) by the sheet in which your C19 is located.

Comment: lol gotta love it when people steal your comment into their answer XD @Neos116 you should look into what Jeeped said.